# Redis save time config. It operates hardisk too often

Tags: python, redis

I'm using redis for python to store and process about 4 million keys and their values. Then I found Redis writes to disk too often. It really cost time. So I change "save 60 10000" in redis config file to "save 60 50000". But it still write to disk every 10000 key changes. I've reboot Redis server.

PS: I want to use dispy and Redis to make my application a distributed program. Is it feasible?  I use "redis dispy distributed system" as keyword and get nothing from Google.

Thank you very much.

Comment: How are you starting your redis-server instance?

Answer (score 0):

I've figure it out.
I'm using win7. Redis server doesn't load the config file each time it runs. I need to load it manually or change save frequency in redis-cli using 'save 60 50000'.